# How is open set defined in linear map space

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I got this statement in my homework:

Prove that the invertible linear contractions are an open set in $Mat(2\times 2;\mathbb{R})$

I know what "invertible linear contraction" , "open set" and $Mat(2\times 2;\mathbb{R})$ are, but when they are combined together, I am very confused.

Especially, how is open set in $Mat(2\times 2;\mathbb{R})$ defined?

Comment: $Mat(2\times 2; \mathbb{R})$ is just a fancy way of looking at $\mathbb{R}^4$ (as far as the topology is concerned). Do you know how an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined?

Comment: Yea, but if we understand in this way, then the statement is weird, because shouldn't a map be in a function space rather than in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: You identify the map with a matrix representing that map. That gives you an isomorphism between the space of linear maps $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. That is a $4$-dimensional real vector space. All $4$-dimensional real vector spaces look the same, though they can have wildly different interpretations.

Comment: So, actually, in the question it's implied that the linear contractions are also resctricted to $\mathbb{R}^4$ vector space? (Because I think linear contraction can be defined in many different vector spaces)

Comment: Linear contractions are defined for all nontrivial vector spaces on which you have a suitable concept of distance, e.g. a norm. Here, we are interested in the matrices in $Mat(2\times 2;\mathbb{R})$, that is in the (invertible) linear contractions of a two-dimensional real vector space (most conveniently, $\mathbb{R}^2$). So you have to show that any matrix that is sufficiently close to the matrix of an invertible linear contraction is itself the matrix of an invertible linear contraction.

Comment: Oh, this clears most of my confusion, but just last question, when do we say that 2 matrices are close, because this still sounds a little bit vague to me.

Comment: You have a norm on that space. Using the operator norm would be very convenient here. Two matrices are "close" if $\lVert A - B\rVert$ is small.